# How to find the height of a recursion tree with addition in the recursive call?

Tags: recursion, tree

I'm trying to find the height of the recursion tree defined by

```
$T(n)=T(\frac{n}{5}+36)+n$
```

I've figured out that at an internal level `$i$`, the recursive call is equivalent to:

```
$$\frac{n}{5^i}+\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}{\frac{36}{5^k}}=\frac{n}{5^i}+36\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}{\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^k}=\frac{n}{5^i} +36\left(\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^i}{1-\frac{1}{5}}\right)=\frac{n-45}{5^i}+45$$
```

Note: that last step is a lot of equation manipulations condensed into one, but I've double checked it's consistent on Wolfram Alpha.

But when I try to find the height of the tree $i$ when the recursive call `$=1$` like this:

```
$$\frac{n-45}{5^i}+45=1$$
After some manipulations:
$$5^i=\frac{45-n}{44}$$
$$i=\log_5{\frac{45-n}{44}}$$
```

But that means `$n$` has to be `$\leq45$` which doesn't make any sense!

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is correct:

[image]

But you have *assumed* a stopping condition of `n <= 1`.

Can this be achieved? Not for `n > 45` – as `i` increases the fraction term will disappear, so the input is asymptotic to `n = 45`. The condition you derived tells you exactly this – `n` can only reach `1` if `n < 45`, i.e. the fraction term is negative.

Of course, you can remedy this by taking the stopping condition to be `n <= C` where `C > 45`. The depth is then:

[image]